Sumbit e-mail to download PDF
I'm having trouble getting this e-mail submission to work;
HTML:
<style>
    /* Basic styling (optional) */
    .container { text-align: center; padding: 20px; }
    #downloadBtn { display: none; } /* Hide button initially */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h4>download our brochure</h4>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required>
    <button id="submitBtn">submit</button>

    <a id="downloadBtn" href="your_pdf_file.pdf" download>Download PDF</a> 
  </div>

  <script src="/public_html/wp-admin/js/emailScript.js"></script>

JS:
const emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
const downloadBtn = document.getElementById("downloadBtn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const email = emailInput.value;
  if (validateEmail(email)) { // (Optional) Add email validation
    // 1. Here, you'd typically send the email to your server/backend for storage/processing.

    // 2. After successful email submission:
    submitBtn.style.display = "none";
    downloadBtn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
  }
});

function validateEmail(email) {
  const excludedDomains = ["hotmail.com", "hotmail.co.uk", "gmail.com", "gmail.co.uk"];
  const domain = email.split("@")[1];

  if (!email.includes("@") || excludedDomains.includes(domain.toLowerCase())) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


For context: I have dropped the .js file into the /public_html/wp-admin/js/ folder of my Wordpress site and directed the HTML there.
On the test page I have created, the submit button does nothing when an e-mail address is entered.
Thanks in advance.
I've tried putting the js file in different places and directing the html; nothing has worked.

Have you tried debugging your code? Ie open the browser's developer tools and checking for errors on the console. Is the script even loaded? When you set some breakpoints are they hit?

In principle your code seems fine jsfiddle The most probable cause for your issue is, that the script can't be loaded from the backend. But as I don't use wordpress I cant help you with that part ...

I've just checked the console and there are indeed errors, thanks:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at index.php?hm_custom_js_draft=1&ver=1715864366:5:11
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

public_html is usually the directory that the domain root points to - so the URL would need to be just /wp-admin/js/emailScript.js then. (Not sure why you would put this into the wp-admin folder to begin with though - this isn't admin backend functionality, but for site visitors - no?)

Brainf*rt from me, I'm assuming it should be in the theme root folder now actually? /public_html/wp-content/themes/salient/js/src/emailScript.js

I've posted the code on a test site I have: https://mentalglasgow.co.uk/

I ran the code and tested it in Visual Studio; it works as intended, so I'm thinking that I'm not linking the .js file properly somehow :/ @CBroe
